# Ruby on Rails set local variable from drop-down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropdown

I'm trying to get the value from a drop down, set it equal to a local variable and display it. All the tutorials I have found use the Post method to store the value in a database.

Is it possible for me to set a local variable equal to what the user selects in the dropdown?

Here is some example code that illustrates what I'm trying to do, I just don't know how to set the selected dropdown value equal to the variable age...

```
<% year = 2017 %>
<p>What is your age?</p>
<%= select_tag "my_age", raw("<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option>") %>
<% birth_year = year - age %>
<%= puts "You were born in #{birth_year}" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you wrote your question, it sounds like you'll want a solution that uses some JavaScript. Ruby executes on the server. If you want your server to know what the user selected, you'll have to send data to your server. That's why the other tutorials you've read `POST` data to the server.

Here's a way you could do this with a little bit of JavaScript:

```
const year = 2017
const my_age = document.getElementById("my_age")

my_age.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
    const age = evt.target.value
    const birth_year = year - age
    console.log("You were born in " + birth_year)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about local variable it is only live in one instance call. With saying that means variable you want use is rendered once before the view is called.
Dropdown you are referring to is form element which should be passed through the form submit. Therefore, it should reload every time you want change `birth_year`. It is no significant different approach if you're using either GET or POST in this case.

In a view:

```
<%= form_tag("/myaction", method: "get") do %>
    <p>What is your age?</p>
    <%= select_tag "my_age", raw("<option>1</option><option>2</option>        
    <option>3</option>") %>
    <%= puts "You were born in #{@birth_year}" %>
<% end %>
```

In a controller:

```
def myaction
    year = Date.today.year
    age = params[:my_age]
    @birth_year = year - age
end
```

On the other hand, if you are planning to use variable in as soon as in client page(frontend) you need set value in Javascript or any other client side frameworks that you are using.